# Trying to create a global npm module. When executing my command I get "The system cannot find the path specified"

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm trying to convert a npm module I created to be used globally. https://github.com/toymachiner62/node-mongo-seeds/tree/global

When I run `$ seed`, it gives the error `The system cannot find the path specified` so it knows that it's a global command.

I'm not sure where to start debugging this. I have `console.logs` in all my scripts and none of them are firing so the problem lies elsewhere, but i'm not sure what to try next.

Advice?

**edit**

I'm now on my mac and I changed the shebang path to node in seed to `#!/usr/local/bin node`.

I still get these errors when trying to use my module:

```
$ seed
-bash: /usr/local/bin/seed: /usr/local/bin: bad interpreter: Permission denied
$ sudo seed
sudo: unable to execute /usr/local/bin/seed: Permission denied
```

**edit**

It seems this is only an issue on one of my macs. The other one works just fine..

Comment: Is it installed with `-g`? Do you know where it is installed? If so -- is that dir on your `PATH`?

Comment: I installed with with `npm install -g ./`. It installs it to `C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules` and `echo %path%` shows `;C
:\Users\m089269\AppData\Roaming\npm` in it

Comment: You probably need to add `C:\Users\...\npm\node_modules\bin` to your `PATH`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should name the script bin/seed.js and call it like that. Also, the path to node seems incorrect at the top of bin/seed.

Comment: Yea the script name works as seed. You don't actually want to have to call `$ seed.js` if it's a global module. You just want to be able to call `$ seed` and have that command actually call `seed.js` which it does.

Comment: I know, I just wanted to point out that you can name the binary command "seed", and your script can still have proper extension, "seed.js".

Comment: The correct shebang to use is this one: `#!/usr/bin/env node`. `#!/usr/local/bin/node` worked on OSX, but not on windows.